# Integer equivalence of binary number that is represented as an integer in Python

Tags: python, binary, integer

I have an input `a=int(1010)`. I want to find integer equivalence of binary `1010`. If I use `bin(a)` then output will be `1111110010`, but I want to get `10`.

Comment: `a=int(1010, base=2)`

Comment: `int() can't convert non-string with explicit base` this error appears when I use `a=int(1010, base=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell python, that your integer **input** is in binary. You can either parse a string with a defined base, or ad a `0b`-prefix to your code constants.

```py
a = int("1010", base=2)
a = 0b1010
print(a)      # result: 10
print(bin(a)) # result: 1010
```